# Limit of an integral involving a general $f(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, definite-integrals

> Let $f:[0,1]\to\Bbb R$ be a continuous function. Calculate
> $$\lim_{{n\to\infty}} \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\ln{n}} \int_0^1 \left( \sqrt{n+1+x+x^2+x^3+\ldots+x^{n-1}} - \sqrt{n} \right) f(x) \, dx.$$

I have absolutely no clue how to solve this kind of limit; I tried rationalization, simplifying it using the GP formula and then trying to break it into different integrals, and using Newton Leibniz rule (and L'Hopital's rule) to differentiate the inner term wrt $n.$ Can anyone please help me out with this?

Comment: Since $f$ is continuous on $[0, 1]$, there exists $M > 0$ such that $\vert f(x) \vert \le M \ \forall x \in [0, 1]$. Thus, 
$$ 
      \left\vert\dfrac{\sqrt{n}}{\ln n}(\sqrt{n + 1 + \ldots + x^{n - 1}} - \sqrt{n})f(x) \right\vert \le M\dfrac{\sqrt{n}}{\ln n}(\sqrt{n + 1 + \ldots + x^{n - 1}} - \sqrt{n}) 
$$
for all $x \in [0, 1]$. By integrate numerically the right hand side, I suspect the limit of the integral should be $0$

Comment: when i plug that integral in wolfram alpha, it shows standard time exceeded so im unable to integrate it numerically and also, what gave you the hint that it should tend to 0?

Comment: The upper bound $\dfrac{\sqrt{n}}{\ln n}(\sqrt{n + 1 + x + \ldots + x^{n - 1}} - \sqrt{n})$ converges to $0$ for $x \in [0, 1)$ and $+\infty$ if $x = 1$

Comment: @ThànhNguyễn I think it is not zero. Simply use: $\sqrt{n+1+x+\ldots+x^{n-1}} - \sqrt{n} = \frac{1 + x  + \cdots + x^{n-1}}{\sqrt{n+1+x+\ldots+x^{n-1}} + \sqrt{n}}
\ge  \frac{1 + x + \cdots + x^{n-1}}{\sqrt{n+n} + \sqrt{n}}$.

Comment: @RiverLi You forgot the term $\dfrac{\sqrt{n}}{\ln n}$

Comment: @ThànhNguyễn I give the details: \begin{align*}
  &\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\ln{n}} \int_0^1 \left( \sqrt{n+1+x+x^2+x^3+\ldots+x^{n-1}} - \sqrt{n} \right)\mathrm{d} x \\
  ={}& \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\ln{n}}
  \int_0^1 \frac{1 + x + x^2 + \cdots + x^{n-1}}{\sqrt{n+1+x+x^2+x^3+\ldots+x^{n-1}} + \sqrt{n}}\,\mathrm{d} x\\
  \ge{}& \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\ln{n}}
  \int_0^1 \frac{1 + x + x^2 + \cdots + x^{n-1}}{\sqrt{n+n} + \sqrt{n}}\,\mathrm{d} x\\
  ={}& \frac{1}{(\sqrt 2 + 1)\ln{n}}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k}\\
  \ge{}& \frac{1}{\sqrt 2 + 1}.
\end{align*}

Comment: So the integral will lie between M(1/(√2+1) and m(1/√2+1) where M and m are respectively the maxima and minima of f(x)..........but in the hints given in the book (sharpening mathematical skills, that's where i got this from), the final answer is an exact value in terms of f(1) and f(0).

Comment: @Cognoscenti I think Svyatoslav's comment makes sense.  It seems the limit is not related to $f(0)$. I wrote a long comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution.**

Let $g_n(x) := 1 + x + x^2 + \cdots + x^{n-1}$. We have
\begin{align*}
 &\sqrt{n + g_n(x)} - \sqrt n\\
 ={}& \sqrt{n}\sqrt{1 + \frac{g_n(x)}{n}} - \sqrt{n}\\[6pt]
 ={}& \sqrt{n} \left(\sqrt{1 + \frac{g_n(x)}{n}} - 1 - \frac{g_n(x)}{2n}\right) + \sqrt{n}\left(1 +  \frac{g_n(x)}{2n}\right) - \sqrt{n}\\[6pt]
 ={}&
 \frac{g_n(x)}{2\sqrt n}
 - \frac{1}{\sqrt n}\cdot \frac{[g_n(x)]^2}{4n + 2g_n(x) + 4\sqrt{n^2 + n g_n(x)}}. \tag{1}
\end{align*}

Using (1), we have
\begin{align*}
 &\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\ln{n}} \int_0^1 \left( \sqrt{n+1+x+x^2+x^3+\ldots+x^{n-1}} - \sqrt{n} \right)f(x)\, \mathrm{d} x \\[6pt]
 ={}& \frac{1}{2\ln n}\int_0^1 g_n(x) f(x)\,\mathrm{d} x
 - \frac{1}{\ln n}\int_0^1 \frac{[g_n(x)]^2f(x)}{4n + 2g_n(x) + 4\sqrt{n^2 + n g_n(x)}} \,\mathrm{d} x\\[6pt]
 ={}& \frac{1}{2\ln n}\int_0^1 g_n(x) f(1)\,\mathrm{d} x + \frac{1}{2\ln n}\int_0^1 g_n(x) [f(x) - f(1)]\,\mathrm{d} x \\[6pt]
 &\qquad - \frac{1}{\ln n}\int_0^1 \frac{[g_n(x)]^2f(x)}{4n + 2g_n(x) + 4\sqrt{n^2 + n g_n(x)}} \,\mathrm{d} x\\[6pt]
 ={}& \frac{f(1)}{2\ln n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k+1} + \frac{1}{2\ln n}\int_{1-1/\ln n}^1 g_n(x) [f(x) - f(1)]\,\mathrm{d} x \\[6pt]
 &\qquad + \frac{1}{2\ln n}\int_0^{1-1/\ln n} g_n(x) [f(x) - f(1)]\,\mathrm{d} x \\[6pt]
 &\qquad - \frac{1}{\ln n}\int_0^1 \frac{[g_n(x)]^2f(x)}{4n + 2g_n(x) + 4\sqrt{n^2 + n g_n(x)}} \,\mathrm{d} x. \tag{2}
\end{align*}

We have
\begin{align*}
 &\left|\frac{1}{2\ln n}\int_{1-1/\ln n}^1 g_n(x) [f(x) - f(1)]\,\mathrm{d} x\right|\\[6pt]
 \le{}& \left(\max_{x\in [1-1/\ln n,\, 1]} |f(x) - f(1)|\right)\cdot  \frac{1}{2\ln n}\int_{1-1/\ln n}^1 g_n(x)\,\mathrm{d} x \\[6pt]
 \le{}& \left(\max_{x\in [1-1/\ln n,\, 1]} |f(x) - f(1)|\right)\cdot  \frac{1}{2\ln n}\int_0^1 g_n(x)\,\mathrm{d} x\\
 ={}& \left(\max_{x\in [1-1/\ln n,\, 1]} |f(x) - f(1)|\right)\cdot \frac{1}{2\ln n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{k+1}\\
 \le{}& 2 \max_{x\in [1-1/\ln n,\, 1]} |f(x) - f(1)| \tag{3}
\end{align*}
where we use $\frac{1}{2\ln n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{k+1} < 2$.
*Note*: $\lim_{n\to \infty} 2 \max_{x\in [1-1/\ln n,\, 1]} |f(x) - f(1)| = 0$.

Let $M := \max_{x\in [0, 1]} |f(x) - f(1)|$. We have
\begin{align*}
 \left|\frac{1}{2\ln n}\int_0^{1-1/\ln{n}} g_n(x) [f(x) - f(1)]\,\mathrm{d} x\right|
 &\le \frac{M}{2\ln n}\int_0^{1-1/\ln{n}} g_n(x) \,\mathrm{d} x \\
 &\le \frac{M}{2\ln n}\int_0^{1-1/\ln{n}} \frac{1}{1 - x} \,\mathrm{d} x\\
 &= \frac{M\ln(\ln n)}{2\ln n} \tag{4}
\end{align*}
where we use $g_n(x) \le \frac{1}{1 - x}$ on $[0, 1 - \frac{1}{\ln n}]$. Also, we have
\begin{align*}
 &\left|\frac{1}{\ln n}\int_0^1 \frac{[g_n(x)]^2f(x)}{4n + 2g_n(x) + 4\sqrt{n^2 + n g_n(x)}} \,\mathrm{d} x\right|\\[6pt]
 \le{}& \frac{1}{\ln n}\int_0^1 \frac{[g_n(x)]^2M}{8n} \,\mathrm{d} x\\[6pt]
 ={}& \frac{M}{8n\ln n}\int_0^{1-1/n} [g_n(x)]^2\,\mathrm{d} x +  \frac{M}{8n\ln n}\int_{1-1/n}^1 [g_n(x)]^2\,\mathrm{d} x\\[6pt]
 \le{}& \frac{M}{8n\ln n}\int_0^{1-1/n} \frac{1}{(1-x)^2}\,\mathrm{d} x + \frac{M}{8n\ln n}\int_{1-1/n}^1 n^2\,\mathrm{d} x\\
 ={}& \frac{M(n-1)}{8n\ln n} + \frac{M}{8\ln n} \tag{5}
\end{align*}
where we use $g_n(x) \le \frac{1}{1 - x}$ on $[0, 1 - 1/n]$,
and $g_n(x) \le n$ for all $x\in [0, 1]$.

From (2)-(5), we have
\begin{align*}
 &\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\ln{n}} \int_0^1 \left( \sqrt{n+1+x+x^2+x^3+\ldots+x^{n-1}} - \sqrt{n} \right)f(x)\, \mathrm{d} x \\[6pt]
 ={}& \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{f(1)}{2\ln n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k+1}
 \\[6pt]
 ={}& \frac{f(1)}{2}.\tag{6}
\end{align*}

Comment: nice detailed solution!

Comment: okay, wow, that was beautiful, thank you very much, it took me about half an hour to work through that but it was so worth it